# One to One Relationship / Unique Key Pairs

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, innodb, normalization

I have a database with two tables, games and regions. My goal is to keep track of the release dates in each region for the games.

Granted, regions wont change very often, but would it be better to create a new column for each region in games, or create a release_dates table between them?

If I create a new table between them, how would I ensure that there is only one release date for each region/game pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the release_dates table.  This keeps you from needing NULL values in your games table if, say, a particular region isn't getting a release.

In your release_dates table, you can make region_id a foreign key and game_id a foreign key, and then make (game_id, region_id) the *primary* key for the release_dates table.  This will ensure each (game_id, region_id) combo appears only once.

Comment: +1 I would name the cross-ref table something like `games_regions` as additional columns can be added in the future without the table name becoming confusing. Plus, it's a more common way to name cross-ref tables (along with `games_x_regions`).

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know you could have a primary key like that. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

It's a many-to-many relationship.  An intermediate junction table containing game_id and region_id is the right solution.